# Getting error Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL while insert into in temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Below is the query where I am getting error

```
Declare @WorldpayAccountKeys varchar(max)='9132E282-2602-4D54-86CF-C93F9A56CF34
,E3759AFF-6968-40C1-8ABD-A25AE9176C1A
,B276D9C8-CC13-47C8-A469-76F8946AF6C0
,BCE689AD-CDC4-42D1-8718-69902ACCA9C3
,BCE689AD-CDC4-42D1-8718-69902ACCA9C4'


    SELECT fooAccountId as abc, T.RowNum, T.Value
    into #temp
    FROM
        (
            SELECT O.Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RowNum
            FROM string_split(@WorldpayAccountKeys,',') O
        ) T
        LEFT JOIN 
            foo R ON R.fooKey= T.Value  
            AND (R.foocId IN (11,12,13,14))
            AND R.fooIndex = 0
```

I know error is for column fooAccountId which is primary key not null, I am getting one null record from this query for column fooAccountId

I have tried, applying null to primary key but it inserted intemp table , why not with above query

> select fooAccountId as abc into #b from foo
> union all
> select null

Needed help, using sql server 2017

Sample query getting error:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WA](
    [WAid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WAKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [WATypeRefKey] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [varchar](111) NULL,
    [AccountToken] [varchar](111) NULL,
    [AcceptorId] [varchar](111) NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [varchar](111) NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VersionOn] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [VersionBy] [varchar](111) NOT NULL,
    [RemovedIndex] [smallint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [WA_PKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [WAid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[WA] ON
GO
INSERT [dbo].[WA] ([WAid], [WAKey], [WATypeRefKey], [AccountId], [AccountToken], [AcceptorId], [ApplicationId], [ClientId], [Version], [VersionOn], [VersionBy], [RemovedIndex]) VALUES (1, N'9132e282-2602-4d54-86cf-c93f9a56cf34', N'Y', N'11', N'11', N'11', N'11', 11, 1, CAST(N'2022-11-30T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), N'test', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[WA] ([WAid], [WAKey], [WATypeRefKey], [AccountId], [AccountToken], [AcceptorId], [ApplicationId], [ClientId], [Version], [VersionOn], [VersionBy], [RemovedIndex]) VALUES (3, N'e3759aff-6968-40c1-8abd-a25ae9176c1a', N'Y', N'12', N'12', N'12', N'12', 12, 1, CAST(N'2022-12-01T18:14:11.5300000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), N'Test', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[WA] ([WAid], [WAKey], [WATypeRefKey], [AccountId], [AccountToken], [AcceptorId], [ApplicationId], [ClientId], [Version], [VersionOn], [VersionBy], [RemovedIndex]) VALUES (6, N'b276d9c8-cc13-47c8-a469-76f8946af6c0', N'Y', N'13', N'13', N'13', N'13', 13, 1, CAST(N'2022-12-01T23:02:40.3164474+05:30' AS DateTimeOffset), N'Test', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[WA] ([WAid], [WAKey], [WATypeRefKey], [AccountId], [AccountToken], [AcceptorId], [ApplicationId], [ClientId], [Version], [VersionOn], [VersionBy], [RemovedIndex]) VALUES (8, N'bce689ad-cdc4-42d1-8718-69902acca9c3', N'Y', N'134', N'14', N'14', N'14', 14, 1, CAST(N'2022-12-01T23:04:04.8758186+05:30' AS DateTimeOffset), N'Test', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[WA] ([WAid], [WAKey], [WATypeRefKey], [AccountId], [AccountToken], [AcceptorId], [ApplicationId], [ClientId], [Version], [VersionOn], [VersionBy], [RemovedIndex]) VALUES (11, N'bce689ad-cdc4-42d1-8718-69902acca9c4', N'Y', N'135', N'15', N'15', N'15', 15, 1, CAST(N'2022-12-06T08:25:23.3533330+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), N'Test', 0)
GO



Declare @WorldpayAccountKeys varchar(max)='9132E282-2602-4D54-86CF-C93F9A56CF34
,E3759AFF-6968-40C1-8ABD-A25AE9176C1A
,B276D9C8-CC13-47C8-A469-76F8946AF6C0
,BCE689AD-CDC4-42D1-8718-69902ACCA9C3
,BCE689AD-CDC4-42D1-8718-69902ACCA9C4'

drop table #temp
    SELECT [WAid] as abc, T.RowNum, T.Value
    into #temp
    FROM
        (
            SELECT O.Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RowNum
            FROM string_split(@WorldpayAccountKeys,',') O
        ) T
        LEFT JOIN 
            [WA] R ON R.[WAKey]= T.Value  
            AND (R.ClientId IN (11,12,13,14))
            AND R.RemovedIndex = 0
```

Comment: So... what's the `ClientId` value for `BCE689AD-CDC4-42D1-8718-69902ACCA9C4`?

Comment: A workaround would be to do `SELECT [WAid]+0 as abc` - it doesn't seem to take proper account that the column can be NULL as that table is outer joined to - maybe because `SELECT INTO` will preserve the `IDENTITY` property

Comment: I removed it to see if the user had passed the variable WorldpayAccountKeys but they didn't exist in my table. This allowed me to determine which @WorldpayAccountKeys were missing.

Comment: ISNULL working for my, but want to know what cause error

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` is causing the error. When `WA` has no matching row then `WAId` will be null.

Comment: yeah but the Query optimiser ought to see that the column is potentially nullable due to the left join and not set the column as not nullable in the table it creates

Comment: Using a `CREATE TABLE` and then a `INSERT INTO` would be a "simple" work around. Or you could put `ISNULL([WAid],NULL) as abc`, which gets around the *feature* too.

Answer (score 0):

The table that this `SELECT INTO` automatically creates is

```
CREATE TABLE  #temp(
    [abc] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RowNum] [bigint] NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

The copying over of the `IDENTITY` property is probably causing the problem as this will require the column to be `NOT NULL`.

The reality is that the output of this column can be null in your query due to the outer join so not compatible with `IDENTITY` (which requires the `NOT NULL`).

You can suppress this copying over of the property by doing a no-op calculation to the column.

e.g.

```
SELECT [WAid]+0 as abc
```

instead of

```
SELECT [WAid] as abc
```

The resultant table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE  #temp(
    [abc] [bigint] NULL,
    [RowNum] [bigint] NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```